# Counting rows with fread without reading the whole file

Tags: r, file, size, data.table, row

I want to use data.table to process a very big file.
It doesn't fit on memory.
I've thought on reading the file on chunks using a loop with (increasing properly the skip parameter).

```
fread("myfile.csv", skip=loopindex, nrows=chunksize)
```

processing each of this chunks and appending the resulting output with fwrite.

In order to do it properly I need to know the total number of rows, without reading the whole file.

What's the proper/faster way to do it?

I can ony think in reading only the first column but maybe there is an special command or trick.
or maybe there is an automatic way to detect the end of the file.

Comment: Maybe the `LaF` package from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19894194/reading-in-chunks-at-a-time-using-fread-in-package-data-table/27535019#27535019 is an option?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**1) count.fields** Not sure if `count.fields` reads the whole file into R at once.  Try it to see if it works.

```
length(count.fields("myfile.csv", sep = ","))
```

If the file has a header subtract one from the above.

**2) sqldf** Another possibility is:

```
library(sqldf)
read.csv.sql("myfile.csv", sep = ",", sql = "select count(*) from file")
```

You may need other arguments as well depending on header, etc.  Note that this does not read the file into R at all -- only into sqlite.

**3) wc** Use the system command wc which should be available on all platforms that R runs on.

```
shell("wc -l myfile.csv", intern = TRUE)
```

or to directly get the number of lines in the file

```
read.table(pipe("wc -l myfile.csv"))[[1]]
```

or

```
read.table(text = shell("wc -l myfile.csv", intern = TRUE))[[1]]
```

Again, if there is a header subtract one.

If you are on Windows be sure that [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) is installed and use this:

```
read.table(pipe("C:\\Rtools\\bin\\wc -l myfile.csv"))[[1]]
```

Alternately on Windows without Rtools try this:

```
read.table(pipe('find /v /c "" myfile.csv'))[[3]]
```

See [How to count no of lines in text file and store the value into a variable using batch script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664761/how-to-count-no-of-lines-in-text-file-and-store-the-value-into-a-variable-using)

Comment: OK, thanks, it works. Unfortunately it doesn't accept the parameter unzip -c name.zip, as fread does.

Comment: With wc you could try `shell("unzip -c name.zip | wc -l")`

Comment: Great!!!.  Now it works.
I guess it won't work if somebody runs my code on a Mac or Linux.

Comment: If you are using platform-specific code then you can check `.Platform$OS.type`  and based on its value provide appropriate code.

Comment: There is a problem with wc.  The output is printed on the screen but cannot be saved on a variable.  PD: I've found I need to add the option intern = T, but there is another problem, the output is not just a number but also the filename.

Comment: See elaboration in answer.

Comment: length(count.fields()) reads in the whole file.

Comment: wc doesn't work in R4.0?

Comment: @wolfsatthedoor, In Rtools40 the path to wc has changed to C:\Rtools40\usr\bin\wc.exe

Answer (score 3):

The [answer by @G. Grothendieck about using `wc -l`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39691214/1355984) is a good one, if you can rely on it being present.

You might also want to look into iterating through the file in chunks, e.g. by employing something [like this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35761217/1355984) that only relies on base R functions.

Since you don't need to read *single* lines, you can read in a batch from a connection. For instance:

```
count_lines = function(filepath, batch) {
    con = file(filepath, "r")
    n = 0
    while ( TRUE ) {
        lines = readLines(con, n = batch)
        present = length(lines)
        n = n + present
        if ( present <  batch) {
            break
        }
    }
    close(con)
    return(n)
}
```

Then you could read the file in, at say 1,000 lines at a time:

```
count_lines("filename.txt", 1000)
```