# R: Simple Random Sample of Massive Dataframe

Tags: r, statistics

I have a massive (8GB) dataset, which I am simply unable to read into R using my existing setup.  Attempting to use `fread` on the dataset crashes the R session immediately, and attempting to read in random lines from the underlying file was insufficient because: (1) I don't have a good way of knowing that total number of rows in the dataset; (2) my method was not a true "random sampling."

These attempts to get the number of rows have failed (they take as long as simply reading the data in:

1. `length(count.fields("file.dat", sep = "|"))`
2. `read.csv.sql("file.dat", header = FALSE, sep = "|", sql = "select
   count(*) from file")`

Is there any way via R or some other program to generate a random sample from a large underlying dataset?

Potential idea: Is it possible, given a "sample" of the first several rows to get a sense of the average amount of information contained on a per-row basis.  And then back-out how many rows there must be given the size of the dataset (8 GB)?  This wouldn't be accurate, but it might give a ball-park figure that I could just under-cut.

Comment: Put it in a SQLite db and grab a random set of rows either directly via RSQLite or via dplyr.

Comment: There are methods like [reservoir sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling) but I don't know of any implementations in common R packages.

Comment: Read first column to get the number of rows (with `col.names`). then read it in in chunks using the `skip` and `nrow` arguments of the `fread` function. Haven't tested it ever but it might work although it will probably be very slow. Every time you get a chunk, get a sample out of it and `rm` it.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39691133/r-data-table-counting-rows-with-fread-without-reading-the-whole-file) contains information on obtaining a row count without reading the file. If you obtain the row count, you might be able to randomly sample from 1 to that row count and read in only that subset.

Comment: I appreciate that post, Nick, but how do you recommend randomly sampling from a dataset?  LyzandeR's method (at least my implementation) is far too slow for my purposes.

Comment: Did you check out the [LaF](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/LaF/index.html) package, this is rather fast to take in chunks of rows ? See a SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19894194/reading-in-chunks-at-a-time-using-fread-in-package-data-table/27535019#27535019)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one option, using the ability of `fread` to accept a shell command that preprocesses the file as its input.  Using this option we can run a `gawk` script to extract the required lines. Note you may need to install gawk if it is not already on your system. If you have `awk` instead on your system, you can use that instead.

First lets create a dummy file to test on:

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(1:1e6, sample(letters, 1e6, replace = TRUE))
write.csv(dt, 'test.csv', row.names = FALSE)
```

Now we can use the shell command `wc` to find how many lines there are in the file:

```
nl = read.table(pipe("wc -l test.csv"))[[1]]
```

Take a sample of line numbers and write them (in ascending order) to a temp file which makes them accessible easily to gawk.

```
N = 20 # number of lines to sample
sample.lines = sort(sample(2:nl, N)) #start sample at line 2 to exclude header 
cat(paste0(sample.lines, collapse = '\n'), file = "lines.txt")
```

Now we are ready to read in the sample using `fread` and `gawk` (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12184784/2761575)). You can also try some of the other gawk scripts in this linked question which could possibly be be more efficient on very large data.

```
dt.sample = fread("gawk 'NR == FNR {nums[$1]; next} FNR in nums' lines.txt test.csv")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  The line `nl = read.table(pipe("wc -l test.csv"))[[1]]` I suspect suffers from the same problems as in my question.  I have had my R console running for 20 minutes, and the line has has yet to terminate. I'm going to try the gawk idea with a ballpark estimate of the rows and get back to you.